# how to put a digital clock in a window made with Glade/GTK in C?

Tags: c, gtk, label, clock, digital

I've been searching on how to create a digital clock on GTK/Glade in C but I couldn't find anywhere :( I guess that I need to use a label right? But what else? How can I pass the computer time, for example, to a label in the window that I've created on glade? Sorry for my bad english but I hope you can understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Actually the "best" would be getting the computer time, but any kinda of functional clock, even if I need to set it when i open the window at first time but somehow it save on it, would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not google it for help? I tried the keywords "gtk clock example" and found the following example:

http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=857

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, i did found that one but its a different version of my Glade and it used libglade, and im using GtkBuilder, but I can use it to put on my window, thank you very much.

Comment: And this answer is a perfect example of why link-only answers are frowned upon: the link is dead. In the future, please quote the relevant pieces in the answer.